# Работа с шаблоном DisplayTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть модель

```
public class viewmodel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательное поле")]
        [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Слишком длинное или короткое поле")]
        [Display(Name = "Имя чувака")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Введи адрес почты")]
        [Display(Name = "Почта")]
        public string mail { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? born { get; set; }
        [Range(2, 5)]
        public int? AnyNum { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть вью

```
<body>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.name)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.name)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.name)<br />
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.mail)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.mail)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.mail)<br />
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AnyNum)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.AnyNum)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AnyNum)<br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="Send" />
        }
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.name)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.mail)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AnyNum)<br />
    </div>
</body>
```

И есть папка переопределяющая шаблон `DisplayTemplates`, в этой папке лежит шаблон для типа стринг. Имеет назавние `String` и модель `string`. 
Вот код шаблона

```
@model string
<span style="color:blueviolet">@Model</span>
```

В данном случае шаблон просто меняет цвет текста. Но почему-то выкидывается эксепшн с таким содержанием `Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "System.Int32", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.String".` когда доходит до `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AnyNum)` - то есть до типа данных Int. Я ранее думал, что если тип отличается от указанного в шаблоне то он просто не обрабатывается этим шаблоном. Но тут выдал эксепшн. Поэтому есть пара вопросов

1. Как сделать, чтобы он видел что это не тот тип данных и просто выводил по дефолту ? (указывать имена шаблона в каждом элементе мне кажется не правильным, потому что предполагается, очень много полей вывода)
2. С чего он вообще вдруг пристал к типу `String` если поле выводит тип Int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что шаблоны применяются к свойствам модели в определенном порядке:

1. Шаблон явно задан в методе `Editor` или `Display`
2. Шаблон задан в атрибуте `UIHint`
3. Шаблон привязан к типу, указанному через атрибут `DataType`
4. Шаблон соответствует имени класса свойства.
5. Если тип свойства - примитивный, используется шаблон `String`
6. Шаблон соответствует базовому типу типа свойства
7. Если тип свойства реализует `IEnumerable`, то используется шаблон `Collection`
8. В противном случае используется шаблон `Object`.

В вашем случае срабатывает правило 5 - для свойств примитивного типа, если не указано иное, всегда используется шаблон `String`.

Исправить достаточно просто - удалите из шаблона модель:

```
<span style="color:blueviolet">@Model</span>
```

Либо используйте любой из способов 1-4, которые имеют более высокий приоритет.